# how to server side render angularjs deployed in iis?

Tags: angularjs, iis, iis-8, server-side-rendering

how to server side render pure angularjs application with html application deployed in iis.How to render this application server side deployed in iis.

Comment: What have been your findings ?

Comment: search engines not indexing for client side rendering

Comment: Siva, you need to put what have you understood and what things you have tried to implement. Your question doesn't reflect any effort that you have put into before posting on SO. That's not how this site works. I hope you are getting my point.

Comment: take a look at https://prerender.io/

Comment: Hi shashank can you provide me your mail id

Comment: presently we are using phantomjs for serverside rendering, but we are facing phantomjs crash problems